# how to yank text from one instance of gvim to another using ex commands

Tags: vim, yank

So I have a lot of lines to copy from one file (open in one instance of gvim) to another file (open in another instance of gvim) and I'm using ex commands. So I tried doing the usual

```
:0,164ya
```

and then going to the other file and doing

```
:pu
```

and I also tried

```
:+0,164ya
```

and then

```
:+pu
```

but neither worked. I also tried using p instead of pu. Anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Try using the `*` or `+` registers to yank and put from the X clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "+ or "* registers:

```
:0,164y +
:put +
```

Answer (score 1):

Vim doesn't sync its register contents across Vim instances. Therefore, you have to use a shared data store like the system's clipboard (register `"+`), or a separate file (`:[range]w /tmp/file`, followed by `:r /tmp/file`).

If you really need to transfer multiple register contents at once (where the approaches above become tedious), you have to explicitly sync the register contents via the *viminfo* file that persists them (among all other history).

In Vim 1:

```
:[range]yank a
:wviminfo
```

In Vim 2:

```
:rviminfo!
:put a
```